# How to open a file if it matches the filename given ( filename obtained using speech recognition)

Tags: python, speech-recognition, python-os

I'm trying to make a script that uses the speech recognition module to listen to your voice and accordingly to what it heard, using that as the filename, if it is in a specific folder (giving the path to it) open the file... However I'm stuck because I can't get the last for loop working (the one that right now should just print the filename if it is in the folder).

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os 


search_path = 'C:/Users/andre/Desktop/foto_coso_python'
result = []

recognizer_instance = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    recognizer_instance.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    print("I'm listening...")
    print()
    audio = recognizer_instance.listen(source)
    #print('Printing what I heard...')

try:
    text = recognizer_instance.recognize_google(audio, language='it-IT').upper()
    print(text)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

list_text = text.split(' ')  #splits the text in single words
#print(list_text)


for root, dir, files in os.walk(search_path):
    for word in list_text:
        if word in files:
            result.append(os.path.join(root, word))


print(result)
```

EDIT
Thanks to @loa_in_ I figured out that loop

```
for word in list_text:
    for root, dir, files in os.walk(search_path):
        for filename in files:
            if word.lower() in filename.lower():
                result.append(filename)
```

Now the ouuput of the code is the file name (if in the folder).

Comment: Did you step through your loop line-by-line with a debugger? What's the value of `word` and `files` in `if word in files:`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows (I assume so from your paths) then you should not really compare filenames as `word in files` because that does a case-sensitive exact match:

- "file" and "File" won't match
- "file" and "File.txt" won't match
- "file" and "file.txt" won't match
- "file" and "this_file_here" won't match
- only "file" and "file" will match

To search for a word in the `files` array in a less strict manner you must loop: `for filename in files` and check if `filename.lower()` contains `word.lower()` - in other words: check for substring after converting both strings to same case (whether it's lowercase or uppercase).

Comment: Ty, I'll try it :)